# Regular expression to validate percentage

Tags: c#, regex

I want to validate input string such that

```
5.0  is correct 
5.5% is correct
```

So I started with the following code:

```
string decimalstring1 = "10000.55";
string decimalstring2 = "5%5%";

string expression = @"^\d|\d%";

Regex objNotNumberPattern = new Regex(expression);

Console.WriteLine(objNotNumberPattern.IsMatch(decimalstring1));
Console.WriteLine(objNotNumberPattern.IsMatch(decimalstring2));
Console.ReadLine();
```

But the problem is that with input like 5%5%  it gives `correct`

How can I modify this expression to make this work?

Comment: In the learning process I'd highly recommend some visual tool, that'd show you on-the-fly what's going on. Personally I use online tools like regexhero or debuggex. Your expression shows me you're matching each digits independently, which would give you a clue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string[] inputs = new string[] {
    "1000.55",
    "1000.65%",
    "100",
    "100%",
    "1400%",
    "5.5",
    "5.5%",
    "x",
    ".%"
};

string expression = @"^\d+[.]?\d*%?$";

Regex objNotNumberPattern = new Regex(expression);
foreach (var item in inputs)
Console.WriteLine(objNotNumberPattern.IsMatch(item));
```

**UPDATE**

```
string expression = @"^(\d+|\d+[.]\d+)%?$";
```

Comment: thanks any idea how to extract the decimal part without the percentage

Comment: Extract? Mmm maybe using groups.

Comment: if (Decimal.TryParse(s_input.Replace("%", ""), out d_input)) {
    decimalPart = d_input - (int) d_input;
}

Answer (score 2):

You get partial matches, because your expression does not anchor both sides. Your regex anchors the beginning, but not the end of the match.

Moreover, the placement of the left anchor `^` is incorrect, because it applies only to the left sub-expression

Adding a `$` at the end should help:

```
^(\d|\d%)$
```

However, this is suboptimal: since the prefix of both expressions is the same, and they differ by an optional suffix `%`, you could use `%?` to simplify the expression:

```
^\d+%?$
```

This is better, but it would not match decimal point. To add this capability, change the expression as follows:

```
^(\d+|\d*[.]\d+)%?$
```

Comment: @Tarec Wow, that's an impressive site for testing regex! Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 1):

You're expression is the following: match when you find either of the following: a single digit at the start of the input string, or a single digit anywhere, followed by %. Probably not what you intended. I'd try something like this:

```
var expression = @"^\d+(\.\d+)?%?$";
```

This would translate to: match a positive number of digits at the start of the string, optionally followed by a dot and any number of digits (fractional part), optionally ending with a % sign.

Comment: @Tarec could you define an unnecessary group? I would counter that the `|` alternative creates an unnecessary repetition of the part to match first digits, which in anything more complex than a single \d+ could become hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this `^\d+([.]\d+)?%?$` it works with: (tested)

```
1000.55
1000.65%
100
100%
1400%
5.5
5.5%
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This matches `X` (or any other single character)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to backslash the dot! Now it should works. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Better, but it will still match for example `.%` (unless that was intended)

Comment: Ok, changed it again, now doesn't match `.%`. Again Thank you @decPL

Comment: Glad to help, one learns every day. By the way - `+` is shorthand for `{1,}`.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is the best one :

```
^\d{0,2}(\.\d{1,4})? *%?$
```

source : [Here](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=277)

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
/(^100([.]0{1,2})?)$|(^\d{1,2}([.]\d{0,2})?)$/
```

For only two decimals and no more than 100 [0.00 - 100.00]