# Regex for percentage checker

Tags: regex

I have a text box which allows users to enter discount percentage. I need a regex for checking its value entered. It should be "0" to "99.99". Tried somethings within my knowledge and that was not perfect.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression to match a percentage with decimal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144276/regular-expression-to-match-a-percentage-with-decimal) or [Regular expression to validate percentage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24679030/regular-expression-to-validate-percentage)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it?

```
preg_match("/(\d{1}|\d{1}\.\d{1,2}|\d{2}|\d{2}\.\d{1,2})%$/", $str);
```

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fWR